# Remove URL structure for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, url, structure, custom-post-type

I would like to know if its possible to remove URL structure for a custom post type. For example, I have 2 custom post types: portfolio and slider.

I want to keep URL structure for portfolio post type like this: mysite.com/portfolio/item-1 etc.

But I dont want URL structure for slider posts, since the slider will only be shown on the home page and I dont want visitors to be able to access it by going to mysite.com/slider/slide-1 for example. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Wordpress forums post: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-url-structure-for-custom-post-type-1?replies=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do register new custom post you're using [`register post type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), right? There are options

```
'rewrite'            => false,
'query_var'          => false,
'publicly_queryable' => false,
'public'             => false
```

After WordPress documentation:

> **`rewrite`** Triggers the handling of rewrites for this post type. To prevent rewrites, set to false.
>
> **`query_var`** 'false' - Disables query_var key use. A post type cannot be loaded at /?{query_var}={single_post_slug}
>
> **`publicly_queryable`** Whether queries can be performed on the front end as part of parse_request().
>
> **`public`** 'false' - Post type is not intended to be used publicly and should generally be unavailable in wp-admin and on the front end unless explicitly planned for elsewhere.

Now go to **Permalinks Settings** and without changing anything - save change. It will rebuild your "routing".

Such setup will disable your custom post from frontend.

Comment: Thank you @speccode that works when I visit mysite.com/slider I get 404 error. But when I visit mysite.com/slider/slide-1 I dont get 404 error but the home displays instead but the url stays the same = mysite/slider/slide-1. I suppose there is very little chance someone would actually try and go to this URL but why does it behave like this? Is there anything more that can be done?

Comment: Go to permalink options and without changing anything just save changes. It will rebuild few things, should help.

Comment: Wow that worked, but it changed the URL from slider/slide-1 to ?post_type=slider&p=33. Any way to get rid of this?

Btw, i was having problems with getting 404 error on custom post type when it would work on others custom post types that i have. I found alot of people had the same problems and one of the solutions was to do what you just described, go to permalinks and just save again. That or using flush_rewrite_rules :)

Comment: Yea, permalinks settings are the easies way if you just creating something for yourself. If you're building plugin you probably should user `flush_rewrite_rules` function when you do activaction/deactivation. Are you sure you set `publicly_queryable` to `false`?

Comment: Yes. Here is the code: just a piece since I cant post whole code in the comment

function rm_slider_custom_post_type() {

 register_post_type('slider',
  array('labels' => array(
   ...
  ),
   'public' => true,
   'publicly_queryable' => false,
            'query_var' => false,
   'exclude_from_search' => yes,
   'menu_position' => 10,
                        'rewrite' => false,
   'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
   )
 ); 
} 

add_action('init', 'rm_slider_custom_post_type');

Comment: @RichardMišenčík, WP, like any other CMS, will always have a link to a post or page. Either if it is by `/some/post` or `?p=36`. It's one of the core priciples with CMS. But permalinks can be customized.

Comment: @RichardMišenčík try to set `public` to `false` too but I'm not sure if it will help. Remember to "refresh" permalinks settings.

Comment: @speccode You are amazing, that works! Make it an answer so I can choose it. Also one more thing, since I have services custom post type, how can I add multiple images to the post? Since with featured image I can only choose one. My services single post contains another small slideshow of product images. Would that be possible somehow? Thanks again and sorry for so many questions. :)

Comment: @speccode Well but how can I use this to attach multiple files to the custom post that Im creating so I can use it similiar to get_post_thumbnail.

Because when I use the Add file at top of the post content, it inserts the images to body content. I need to be able to use them in php with template tags. Something like get_post_thumbnails(); and then create a while statement and echo them out.

Comment: When you uploading images to post it will be set as attached to post. **You don't have to insert it to post**. Then: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Comment: @speccode Thanks. Even tho sometimes when I just upload the images and close the window it doesnt insert them, but mostly it does so no problem.

So when Im using the single-services.php template, do I need to use the the <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> loop? Or can I just use the code example from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image to output the image attachments without the loop? Thanks much.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40456/discussion-between-speccode-and-richard-misencik)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, in my case I had custom post type like this:

```
mypage.com/type
```

and inside I've got a lot of posts, so of course this generated for me pages looks like:

```
mypage.com/type/page1
mypage.com/type/page2
...
```

BUT, I knew that in the future I'll make websites there, so simple I made a redirection inside this custom post type webpages. So inside single-type.php I added:

```
<script>
    window.location.href='www.mypage.com/404';
</script>
```

So this simply redirect people to 404 page. Few weeks later, when I wanted to turn on these pages, I just deleted this code.

This is just a temporary workaround, but I hope it could help someone.